# Why can't I implement one of my Wpf behaviors as an EventTrigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following Xaml where I'm using a behavior to activate my Login window:

```
<Window ...
 xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:"..."
 xmlns:interactivity="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
 .
 .>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:ActivateBehavior Activated="{Binding Activated, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
 .
 .
 </Window>
```

together with the corresponding Behavior that reacts on the OnActivated event for a Window:

```
public class ActivateBehavior : Behavior<Window>
{
.
. (here goes some other code like the DP Activated)
.

protected override void OnAttached()
{
    AssociatedObject.Activated += OnActivated;
    AssociatedObject.Deactivated += OnDeactivated;
}

protected override void OnDetaching()
{
    AssociatedObject.Activated -= OnActivated;
    AssociatedObject.Deactivated -= OnDeactivated;
}

void OnActivated(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    _isActivated = true;
    Activated = true;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(App.UserId))
    {
        LoginView loginView = new LoginView();
        loginView.ShowDialog();
    }
}

void OnDeactivated(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    _isActivated = false;
    Activated = false;
}
```

}

You can implement this in code-behind by using the following code:

```
    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnActivated(e);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(App.UserId))
        {
            LoginView loginView = new LoginView();
            loginView.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

but since I'm only working with MVVM this is not an option. Now, my qustion is why this cannot be implemented with an EventTrigger instead, i.e., using the following code in my xaml:

```
<Window ...
 xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:"..."
 xmlns:interactivity="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
 .
 .>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Activated">
            <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnActivatedCommand}" />
        </interactivity:EventTrigger>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
 .
 .
 </Window>
```

with the following command in my NotesViewModel.cs:

```
public RelayCommand OnActivatedCommand { get; set; }
```

and in my NotesViewModel constructor:

```
        OnActivatedCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(App.UserId))
            {
                LoginView loginView = new LoginView();
                loginView.ShowDialog();
            }
        });
```

With this implementation the command is never hit which means the EventTrigger "Activated" is never hit.

I know there's another discussion whether you should reference another view in the ViewModel but that's not what I'm out for here, I just want to know why I can't use Interaction.Triggers and EventTrigger to fire the event Activated instead of using Interaction.Behaviors (which nevertheless should be the MVVM Purist way I would say)?

Thanks.

Comment: *"but since I'm only working with MVVM this is not an option"* - You get some fundamental things wrong. MVVM does not ban code-behind. It doesn't even bother with it. Code-behind is a pure language i.e. compiler feature. In fact code-behind is not there for esthetics. It's there because not all GUI related logic can be implemented in XAML. Your conclusion to move such code to the View Model is the true violation. Controls, and dialogs are controls, must be handled in the View and not in the View Model. So make your life easier and implement in code-behind what needs to go there.

Comment: EventTrigger is a trigger that triggers on routed events. If Activated is not a routed event that is raised by a child of listener's visual tree, you won't be able to trigger on it. [Routed events overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/routed-events-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0)

Comment: As Window can't have a parent element, it doesn't make sense to define Window.Activated as a routed event. To handle this event simply define an override of OnActivated in code-behind of the Window type (as you intuitively already did).

Comment: If you want to define an EventTrigger, take a look at the Window.Loaded event. It may be an adequate replacement for the Activate event. [FrameworkElement.Loaded Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). But I recommend to override the virtual event handler OnActivated or in case of the Loaded event, to register a common event handler in code-behind (unless you need to start an animation).

Comment: The conventional way will simplify your code. It will also fix your design issues in terms of MVVM.

Comment: @BionicCode, let's agree to disagree on your first comment. The whole idea with the pattern, i.e. Model, View, ViewModel is to separate things to make the code more maintainable, and with that more testable. For the record, I do code-behind when I need DependencyProperties. But that's about it. I have been working with code-behind way back but came to the conclusion that code-behind should be really sparse.

Comment: @PeterCentellini Mostly right, but applied wrong. MVVM pattern was never meant to be applied to controls, its for your application logic. When you write a general purpose control, i.e. a calendar control or a drop down box etc., you don't apply MVVM on it. You do most of of its logic in its code behind class and that's fine and the way it should be. Trying to apply MVVM on general purpose controls will bite you hard as it was never a supported scenario for MVVM. You always have to know WHERE and WHEN to apply a pattern. Blindly applying it everywhere leads to nothing but complications

Comment: @Tseng How is it applied wrong? I never intended to use the MVVM pattern with controls (as you can see in my example as well). Also, having used patterns in many various situations (GoF and others) during my last 20+ years in coding I'm also very aware how things can get "religious" when applying patterns, especially with "pattern-newbies".

Comment: @Tseng With that being said, I'm using code-behind where applicable, or where the situation requires that path to simplify things. Especially with Dependency Properties, but I don't understand your suggested approach where you say that one should do most of the logic in code-behind with controls.

Comment: @Tseng Again, I never talked about user control development, and I definitely didn't talk about, as you put it, "..trying to apply MVVM on general purpose controls..". Don't know why you thought that. No, developing controls or not (since you brought that up), the important thing is to look at the full picture, and not get stuck with a specific pattern. I can just say that you totally misinterpreted my question.

Comment: Well, first and foremost, an `Behavior<T>` is part of the View (The V in M-V-VM), so it knows nothing about View Models and the likes. View VM depends on M, and most of the Views are special type of controls which are done with binding. That being said, you mustn't apply VM or any MVVM practices on the `ActivateBehavior`. If you want more flexibility, you'd just add another DP (i.e. `ViewName`)  and use a service locator to resolve the View instances, i.e. `ServiceLocator.GetView(ViewName)` and bind that in your code `<behaviors:ActivateBehavior Activated="{...}" ViewName="LoginView"/>`

Comment: Its mostly been acceptable to use a service locator (though my WPF times a couple of years ago) for navigation service or inside views, but of course discouraged for rest of your code (VMs, Models etc.). Generally there been two ways to do navigations, strings -> View resolving via IoC or ViewModel -> View, where you'd use the ViewModel type (more commonly used when navigation is implemented close to the viewmalde, i.e. `navigationService.Navigate<LoginViewModel>();`

Comment: In both cases one register their Views with their dependency injection of choice, either via two types or as a named dependency (when using strings for view resolving)

Answer (score 1):

I have also observed that `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.EventTrigger` with `Window.Activated` event fails to fire when a Window opens for the first time but succeeds when the Window is activated for the second time and after.

The test code is quite plain.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfInteractionTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfInteractionTest"
        Width="600" Height="400">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Activated">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnActivatedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

</Window>
```

Then, I have found that it succeeds to fire even for the first time in the following code.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfInteractionTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfInteractionTest"
        Width="600" Height="400">

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Activated" SourceObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnActivatedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

</Window>
```

I have no clear idea but guess the order in initialization process of Window affects this issue. Anyways, `Window.Loaded` event seems to work well and so it  would be an alternative as suggested.

[Test project](https://github.com/emoacht/WpfTriggerTest)

Answer (score 0):

> With this implementation the command is never hit which means the EventTrigger "Activated" is never hit.

It should work assuming your `DataContext` is set up correctly and the binding works. Did you confirm that the window was actually activated? Try to mimimize and restore it.

Or maybe you want to handle the `Loaded` event instead of, or in combination with, `Activated`.